# Найти элементы в массиве по совпадениям

Tags: javascript, jquery

Условно есть массив
a = ['lalala','blalala','sobaka','koshka'];

Как найти определенные элементы по совпадению?
Например, когда вписываю в инпут 'ka', мне должно выдать 'sobaka' и 'koshka'. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто, если применить `toLowerCase`, `includes` и `filter`

```
const arr = ['lalala','blalala','sobaka','koshka']
const inputText = 'la';

console.log(arr.filter((text) => text.toLowerCase()
  .includes(inputText.toLowerCase())
))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!